# Repeater control with strongly typed objects entity framework

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I am new to entity framework, and wondered if someone could help. I have 2 classes that define documents and then their versions (1 to many relationship).

I am using the asp:repeater to display the list of documents, but cannot access information re the versions.

The 2 classes are below

```
Public Class Document
  <Key>
  Public Property ID As Guid
  Public Property Name As String
  Public Property Description As String
  Public Property CreationDate As Date
  Public Property ReviewDate As Date
  Public Property NextReview As Date
  Public Overridable Property Versions As ICollection(Of DocumentVersion)
End Class

Public Class DocumentVersion
  <Key>
  Public Property VersionID As Guid
  <ForeignKey("Document")>
  Public Property DocumentID As Guid
  Public Property FilePath As String
  Public Property CreationDate As Date
  Public Overridable Property Document As Document
End Class
```

In the asp:repeater I'm using `<%#: Item.Name %>` to display the document name, but cannot access `<%#: Item.Versions.FilePath %>` for example.

If I do include item.versions.filepath I get the error:
BC30456: 'FilePath' is not a member of 'ICollection(Of DocumentVersion)'.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Versions is an ICollection of DocumentVersion. You'll have to specify which Version's FilePath you want to display

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible to specify that in the in the include with a separate WHERE ?

Comment: in the include it's not possible, however you could use the select function to select the appropriate one (you'll have to save in a dynamic/temporary data type then)

Comment: Sounds like you need a repeater for the the list of documents, then a second nested repeater for the list of versions.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'm having trouble understanding the select function to select specific (newest) version. Any advice?